# Isometries of Sine Curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, isometry

I am trying to find all of the isometries of a sine curve. I found four isometries (the identity, rotating by 180 degrees, shifting by a multiple of $2 \pi,$ and reflecting over a vertical line). My question is - how do I create a multiplication table for these operations? I tried looking at how different transformations affect points (like a translation followed by a rotation), but haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: There are only seven [frieze groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group).

Comment: Could you explain? So I can't compose a translation with a reflection, say?

Comment: This frieze group is p2mg, with Vertical reflection lines, Glide reflections, Translations and 180° Rotations. A translation composed with a reflection is another reflection with a different axis.

Comment: @Analytical You wrote that you found four isometries. In fact, there are infinitely many of them. The identity is unique, of course. But, for each $n\in\mathbb Z$, you have a rotation by $180^\circ$ around $n\pi$, a shift byr $2\pi n$, and a reflection on the vertical line $x=\frac{n\pi}2$.

Comment: I know, but I was trying to classify them into sections. Is there a general formula for composing two arbitrary elements in the group?

Comment: @Analytical Yes. The composition of two distinct $180^\circ$ rotations is a translation. The composition of two distinct reflections in two parallel lines is a shift (twice as long as the distance between the lines). The composition of two shifts is another shift (surprise, surprise!). Try to determine the remaining cases.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was able to work out all of them, except for a rotation followed by a reflection. Can a rotation followed by a reflection be simplified?

Comment: @Analytical Sure. It's another of your reflections.

Comment: A little remark : the term rotation is slightly misleading here: there are only 180° rotations which are plainly symmetries wrt a point.

Comment: @Analytical I've just noticed that you did not find *all* isometries. There is still this possibility: a reflection on the $x$-axis followed by a shift by a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're right, that's a fifth. Is there any way to prove that these are all of the isometries? Or is it just a matter of looking at the curve?

Comment: @Analytical You can prove that there are no more looking at the [classification of plane isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_plane_isometry#Classification_of_Euclidean_plane_isometries) and choosing those that map the curve into itself.